# How to redirect default.aspx to root directory?

Tags: c#, seo

I would like to redirect home page (sapphireenterprises.net/default.aspx) to sapphireenterprises.net/ to tackle duplicate  content issue from SEO point of view.
I tried many rewrite rule in web config but none of them work properly many of them create redirect loop please help me. Please guide me to add c# programming on code behind page..

Answer (score 1):

Just put

Response.Redirect("/");

In the page load event.

Comment: Sir it is creating redirect Loop.

Comment: If you have default.aspx set as a default document on your web server then it will do. That solution does what you have asked for, you just need to configure everything else correctly.